# Trying to write a script to kill a program automatically (mac/unix - kill tomcat)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

by hand, here is the process:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

The results of this look like:

`0 39107     1   0  5:40PM ttys004    5:22.34 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/local/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms384m -Xmx768m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/local/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /opt/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/local/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/local/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/local/tomcat7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`

the second number is the pid.

Then I do

```
sudo kill tomcat_pid
```

How can I automate this?

ps. I know there is a shutdown.sh script. I've tried it but it never works.

Comment: Check out `pidof` and `killall`...?

Comment: @moonshadow pidof is linux specific. I am using a mac

Comment: @moonshadow and to use killall I'd have to kill all java processes on my machine which is not what I want

Comment: [obligatory](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill` will extract that second number and pass it to `kill`. Actually, you'll probably want `ps -efww` to make sure you get the whole command line.

This really isn't the nicest way to do this; ideally, you should store the PID when you create the process you'll later want to kill, to make sure you don't kill things that accidentally happen to match the string you're searching for (amongst other potential problems).

Comment: eeeeew... `xargs`. +1 for recommending `$!` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this is my script for Ubuntu Linux uses bash 
its not automatic but finding and killing tomcat comes to
pressing enter if you do want to kill a process and typing process number manually.

```
#/bin/bash
if [ `whoami` != root ]; then
    echo "Please run this script as root or using sudo"
    exit
fi
echo
echo "finding proceses that have name java and established connections status"
echo
echo "Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name"
netstat --tcp --numeric --programs  | grep "ESTABLISHED" | grep "java"
echo 
echo "finding proceses that use port 8080"
echo
netstat --tcp --numeric --programs | grep ":8080" 
echo -n "Do you wish to kill a process listed above?[Y/n]"
read choose
if [ "$choose" = "Y" ] || [ "$choose" = "y" ] || [ -z "$choose" ]
then 
echo "enter pid to kill"
read procesId
kill -9 $procesId
fi
echo "done exiting"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script for kill all running tomcat process using bash script

```
  #!/bin/sh
  ARG=$1 
  for file in `find /proc -regex /proc/[0-9]+ 2> /dev/null`; do
     if `grep --silent org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap $file/cmdline 2> /dev/null`; then 
          base=`basename $file`
          echo "Trying to " kill $ARG $base "tomcat process"
          kill $ARG $base
     fi  
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`pkill -f catalina; sleep 3`

**pkill:** look up or signal processes based on name and other.
**sleep 3**: wait for 3 seconds, useful when trying to start tomcat right away.